# I forgot or I had forgotten in this example?

Tags: past-perfect, past-simple

Example:
After leaving the grocery store, it dawned on me that I forgot to buy a cucumber.

In my opinion "I forgot" should be "I had forgotten". 
What is correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Canonical Post #2: What is the perfect, and how should I use it?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/canonical-post-2-what-is-the-perfect-and-how-should-i-use-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find *I had forgotten* to be more natural here; but *I forgot* is also possible. When the sequence of events is clear, we don't always use the past perfect.